Fortify - C# Return File - Flagging XSS: Reflected
This code, downloads pdf file but after scanning on Fortify, flagged XSS Reflected on marked code.
How can i solve this issue?

I validated this file content as pdf but not accepted by Fortify as secure.
if (contentType.Contains("application/pdf"))

the keyword is in the report, "XSS Reflected" - i guess fortify thinks that fileName "printed" into end user's browser even though it will be in the HTTP header Content-Disposition assuming this File is an aspnet BaseController helper method. just guess, show us the actual report's source and sink for further consideration.

also WebClient is quite dated. please use HttpClient - even better if you are on newer aspnet core you can inject IHttpClientFactory instead for connection pools.
